# Collecting a dump from a .net core app running inside a container

Tags: docker, .net-core, memory-leaks, azure-aks

I have a scenario in a .net core 2.1 app running inside a container with an image from mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.1 deployed on a AKS cluster.

I'm trying to get a memory dump to find a memory leak on my app and found a way using https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/Documentation/botr/xplat-minidump-generation.md#configurationpolicy.

Using kubectl exec I'm not reaching the container with root access so createdump don't have privileges to execeute. Did anyone here had a similar issue? Any clue on how to solve? Thanks

Comment: Maybe this is helpfull: Getting memory dump .net core aks container  https://thinkrethink.net/2021/02/17/memory-dump-net-core-linux-container-aks/

Answer (score 2):

Just have a look at the links below. For the first one you should use kubeclt node-shell to connect to aks node. In the second one, sidecar pattern is used for dumping memory of the container. The third one you can dump and get the memory directly from clients browser

- https://github.com/6opuc/lldb-netcore-use-cases
- https://medium.com/@pamir.erdem/how-to-dump-oomkilled-process-on-kubernetes-b77cccf421a2
- https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/introducing-dotnet-monitor/